# Implementing Joomla update system for extension hosted on Github

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, update, github, extension-update

I have a number of Joomla extensions on the JED. I haven't set up a site for them; I'm just pointing JED at their location on Github. I've also never implemented auto-update for any of them.

JED now has a new policy that extensions must implement auto-update, so I'm going to have to think about how to do this, and I'd like to ask here for some advice.

I've avoided doing the updates before mainly because, having the extension served directly from a Github repo, I didn't know where I could put the update feed XML file.

Is it acceptable for the update XML to be part of the main repository? If so, where in the repo should I put it? And also, what URL would I give for it to the JED? I assume I'd have to give a link directly to the master branch; is that right?

Does anyone have any tips or other relevant info on managing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can put the `update.xml` in the main repository.

As for the link to provide JED, you'll need to open the file on Github, then click "Raw", so you URL will look something like this:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPO-NAME/master/path-to-file/update.xml

And also be sure to reference this URL in your extension's XML file too.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply! That's really helpful. Thank you. I'll give it a go and if all goes well I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Is there a specification for the update xml anywhere? I've got example files, but I can't see anywhere that defines exactly what should be in each element, what's optional, etc.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server

Comment: Thanks again. I managed to miss that page. I have now completed adding the auto update feature to one of my plugins and have updated it on the JED. Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @Simba - glad it's all working now :)